# What is MavenProject.managedVersionMap

Tags: java, maven

While writing a maven plugin I found a field in the [MavenProject](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html) class named "managedVersionMap". While on debug it contains alot of entries.

It looks to be a map that contains a String built by the <groupId>:<artifactId> mapped to an Artifact of that maven project.

While it looks like something that I might need for my plugin i can not be certain, because this field is not documented and my search didn't yield the needed answers, so here is my question for you.

What does the MavenProject.managedVersionMap contain?

Comment: So my first question is: What does your plugin should do? What purpose ?

Comment: @khmarbaise My plugin should print all dependencies of the root Project - in contrast to the dependency:tree plugin, which lists only the dependencies of the current project. I didn't add that information, because I didn't think it's important for the answer of my question

Comment: Why not helping to enhance the maven-dependency-plugin with that functionality ? The point in the root project in a multi module project is that it has no dependencies at all only a dependencyManagement part which is a different thing... The point is the map will not help here in any way for solving that problem...and that's why it is important to add such information....

Comment: That is absolutely correct.
My point is to print all of the dependencies of a project independently of where the plugin is ran from. For example, if you want to write the dependencies in some kind of a documentation, then you only need to compile the documentation module.
In this way you skip the call of dependency:tree on the parent pom to create that list of dependencies.

Comment: @khmarbaise you are right, I should help the maven-dependency-plugin with this, but i, for one, don't know what that list does and my current solution is atrocious.